# .NET CORE 3.1, MVC Async method not updating DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, async-await

AI am just moving to ASYNC methods and trying to get my data to update.  I can select just find so I know the repository is working.

Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditTeam(EmployeeVm empVm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", _errorUpdateMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            if (await _teamRepository.UpdateEmployee(empVm.Employee))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", _errorUpdateMsg);
        }

        return View(empVm);
    }
```

My Constructor in repo

```
    public TeamRepository(EnvisionDbContext envisionDbContext)
    {
        _envisonDbContext = envisionDbContext;
    }
```

Here is my Update that does not save

```
    public async Task<bool> UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        var result = await _envisonDbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync<Employee>(e => e.Id == employee.Id);

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            result.LastName = employee.LastName;
            result.Phone = employee.Phone;
            result.IsActive = employee.IsActive;

            await _envisonDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATED:  If I add this, it works.  Is this because the two await calls are disconnected?

```
            result.IsActive = employee.IsActive;
            _envisonDbContext.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: What are you seeing in your logging? Have you tried to profile the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forgot update-method before savingchanges

```
if (result != null)
    {
        result.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
        result.LastName = employee.LastName;
        result.Phone = employee.Phone;
        result.IsActive = employee.IsActive;

        _envisionDbContext.Update(result); //paste it before you save changes

        await _envisonDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return true;
    }
```